# Estimating precision & recall

Tags: text-mining, model-evaluations

Given a very large population, is there an accepted recall estimation method to use when one is validating a trained model against the population?

In my case, a trained model was tested on a disjoint data set, so it has test precision and recall values, but the test data is an extremely small fraction the population.

When the model is run against 'live' data, and when I look at randomly sampled results, I observe an overfit. I want to estimate how bad the situation is, so it makes sense to estimate precision and recall estimates in the population.

I can think of a way to do this for precision calculations, as one can randomly select from the classifier's positive outcomes at various times to calculate a sample mean and standard deviation for precision. However, it does not appear to be easy to estimate recall in the case of drastic class imbalance, and samples drawn from the population keep coming up with zero positive-class data points.

Has anyone come across a situation like this? I would appreciate any pointers or reference materials on the subject.

Comment: Why not just make the test set larger? That has to be the simplest and most efficient way of improving the accuracy of the estimate. Also, are you using a separate cross-validation set (or k-fold cross-validation) for tuning your model, or using results on the test set for tuning?

Comment: Thanks Neil. It makes sense to increase the size. How large is sufficient enough to represent the population so I have a proper representation of the skew? To answer your question, I am using a separate data set to tune the model.

Comment: I don't think anyone could answer "how large" without knowing a lot more about your data. Personally I would not know how to calculate the optimum, just that more test data equate to better error bars on your accuracy estimate. It is typical to reserve e.g. 20% of total data set as a final test set, as a compromise between having more data to train with vs understanding the metrics of your model accurately. If you have a single CV set, you might split train/cv/test as 60/20/20.